# Words for a person who imposes

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, phrase-requests, synonyms, pejorative-language

I need a few words that describe a person who is imposing, in a context of overstaying his welcome. Someone that is present unwelcomed and you can't do your usual routines until the person is gone. A person who is not part of the household and is in the way. And excess person → *freeloader, parasite, scrounger/unwelcome guest*. Something more specific.

Comment: I'm fond of "interloper", but I fear it may be no more specific than the words you've already listed.

Comment: How about "burden": `Something that is emotionally difficult to bear.` or ` A source of great worry or stress`

Comment: Moocher, Maybe?

Comment: If they are using your resources: "sponger", "leech", "deadbeat"?

Comment: Are you aware of the word "imposer" ?

Comment: No suggestions, but Ben Franklin is reputed to have said, "Guests, like fish, begin to smell after three days" (and in the South in the U.S., folks add, "and need to be pitched out"!).
Read more at http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/b/benjaminfr151622.html#p3Qjg3AzyD3VWEJ2.99

Comment: Could you please explain why _freeloader_ and _parasite_ are unsatisfactory? Those are already quite specific, so I'm afraid you may be setting an impossible goal for answers.

Comment: 1. Your question is fundamentally flawed. 2. You may be looking for good 'abuse words' to add to your list, which is probably off-topic on ELU. 3. You already know 'one who has overstayed his welcome' that is apt and good enough.

Comment: This post may be closed if only for its potential to become a "primarily opinion-based" case.

Comment: How about "burden"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alternatives to ***imposer***

**Intrusive** and [***intruder***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/intruder?s=t)

> 1. tending or apt to intrude; coming without invitation or welcome: intrusive memories of a lost love.
>
> 2.
>   characterized by or involving intrusion.
>
> 3.
>   intruding; thrusting in.

***Obtrusive*** and [***obtruder***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obtruder?s=t)

> having or showing a disposition to obtrude, as by imposing oneself or one's opinions on others.

Depending on the circumstances. Both words are etymologically related and derive from the Latin stem *trudere* giving the sense of *thrusting* ***in*** or ***toward.***

***Meddling*** and [***meddler***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/meddler?s=t)

> to involve oneself in a matter without right or invitation; interfere officiously and unwantedly:
>
> *Stop meddling in my personal life!*

Comment: These are easily transformed into nouns using conventional grammar.